# Программно не отображается UINavigationBar, чего не хватает?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Я создал программно UINavigationBar, но он не отображается, что сделать чтоб он отобразился с кнопкой стиля UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
nnavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
nnavBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
nnavBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo target:nil action:@selector(doneInfoView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}

-(void) doneInfoView
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу тут 2 ошибки:

1. Ты создал НавигатионБар, а как приложению понять куда ты его поместить хочешь? :) Ты его не добавил.
2. То же самое с Кнопкой, как приложению понять, что ты его в созданный бар помещаешь? :)

Ответ:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    nnavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    nnavBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    nnavBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo target:nil action:@selector(doneInfoView)];

    UINavigationItem * navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [nnavBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:nnavBar];
}
```